# Network Manager 16.04 Weird Bug

Tags: 16.04

Unless I restart network manager via the terminal (sudo service network-manager restart), it turns into the below screenshot after a suspend/resume.

[image: screenshot]

Everything else works ok.  I had other graphical issues after a resume from sleep but the 4.7 mainline kernel fixed those.

Ubuntu 16.04 Dell e4310.

Comment: This an old bug. I have this problem too for a veeeery long time.

Comment: I made an alias for that command and run just `wifi` to restart.

Comment: Yup, I can confirm it is an old but also mostly harmless bug.

Comment: Ok thanks guys.  Is there a way to make a script that will restart the network manager after a fresh boot?  Once I restart network manager, suspend and resumes do not trigger this bug.

Comment: I faced same problem. But when I install new desktop environment (KDE plasma), then it fixed.

Comment: Hmm so it's the unity network manager...

Comment: Anyone know how to resolve this?  So annoying that the first terminal command I've memorized is sudo service network-manager restart